# PyQt5 not working on macOs sierra

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, macos-sierra

I have been trying to use the pyqt5 library for close to over an 5 hours now, it keeps on saying:-

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
```

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so, 2):
>   Library not loaded: @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so
>   Reason: image not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got it working , after 1 million fruitless tries.

1. Get homebrew then brew install pyqt.
2. `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/qt/include pip3 install PyQt5` all on 1 line.

Then viola !

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate a bit please ?

Comment: install hombrew - https://brew.sh/(go here for details on how to install)

Comment: then type brew install pyqt on your terminal window, after installing pyqt5 you should type LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/qt/include pip3 install PyQt5 all on 1 line on your terminal window.

Comment: Is this a bug in the PyQt5 installer? I tried several other posts but only this worked for me. Using OSX and Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem with pyqt installed via conda, when importing the following:

`from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore`

Updating the package solved the problem for me.

`pyqt: 5.6.0-py36_1 conda-forge --> 5.6.0-py36h8210e8a_6 conda-forge`

Note that there's also a new version available (pyqt 5.9.2), but this update resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to Python 3.6. on OSX